# PHP/sqlsrv_query resource id is 3 but does not return data

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a simple stored proc -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ws_s_GetCargoClearanceApproval_t]
    @BOLID INT,
    @ACCOUNTID INT,
    @TOTALAMOUNT FLOAT OUT,
    @STORAGEDAYS INT OUT,
    @ACCOUNTCREDIT FLOAT OUT,
    @CREDITLIMIT FLOAT OUT
AS

BEGIN
--SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @TOTALAMOUNT= '25.00'; SET @STORAGEDAYS = 5; SET @ACCOUNTCREDIT =2500.00;  SET @CREDITLIMIT=75000.00 ;
    SELECT @TOTALAMOUNT,@STORAGEDAYS,@ACCOUNTCREDIT,@CREDITLIMIT;
END
```

---

This is called by a php file and the code is -

```
<?php
$bol_id = 426863;
$account_id = 26293;
$totalamount = 0.00;
$storagedays = 0;
$accountcredit = 0.00;
$creditlimit = 0.00;

$param1 = array($bol_id, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN);
$param2 = array($account_id, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN); 

$param3 = array($totalamount, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT); 
$param4 = array($storagedays, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT);
$param5 = array($accountcredit, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT); 
$param6 = array($creditlimit, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT);


$params = array($param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, $param5, $param6);

$tsql = "{call usp_ws_s_GetCargoClearanceApproval_t(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";  

$Account_Transaction_List = array();

$connectionInfo = array(  "Database"=>'**', "UID"=>'**', "PWD"=>'***');
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( "**", $connectionInfo );

if( $conn === false ) {
    echo "Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $this->servername.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
    echo "Connected!";
}
echo '<br/>';   

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);
echo "<pre/> $result - ";print_r($result);
echo '<br/>';   

if ($result !== NULL) {  
    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows( $result );
    if ($rows === true)  
        echo "\nthere are rows\n";  
    else   
        echo "\nno rows\n";  
}  

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo 'IN <br/>';
}

?>
```

It returns:

> Connected!
>
> Resource id #3 - Resource id #3
>
> no rows

No matter what i try i don't get data. I have tried passing the params by ref, setting cursor options to the connection and other permutations for the last two days, no luck.

Did anyone come across this issue. Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried testing the stored procedure on its own?

Comment: `Resource id #3` just means that the query was successful, it does not mean that it will return rows. So definitely try the procedure on its own and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it guys. the sp returns values when run on sql server management studio. as you can see the sp itself is very straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem I notice is that `$creditlimit` is set to `SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT`. I'd suggest checking [`sqlsrv_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php) after running the query. There may be warnings getting returned that shed some light on the situation. Try something like this:

```
<?php
$bol_id        = 426863;
$account_id    = 26293;
$totalamount   = 0.00;
$storagedays   = 0;
$accountcredit = 0.00;
$creditlimit   = 0.00;

$params = [
    [$bol_id,        SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$account_id,    SQLSRV_PARAM_IN],
    [$totalamount,   SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT],
    [$storagedays,   SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT],
    [$accountcredit, SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT],
    [$creditlimit,   SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT],
];

$conn = sqlsrv_connect("**", ["Database" => "**", "UID"=> "**", "PWD" => "***"]);

if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $this->servername.<br />";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
    echo "Connected!<br/>";
}

$tsql = "{CALL usp_ws_s_GetCargoClearanceApproval_t(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}";  

$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql, $params);

if ($err = sqlsrv_errors()) {
    echo "There were errors or warnings!<br/>";
    print_r($err);
    echo "<br/>";
}

if ($result && sqlsrv_has_rows($result)) {
    echo "There are rows<br/>";
} else {
    echo "There are no rows<br/>";
}

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    print_r($row);
    echo "<br/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you miken32, it works. The interesting bit is, i did try just with SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT. Anyways alls well that ends well.

Answer (score 0):

apparently, sqlsrv extension has issues drawing data which is computed in the sp. previously my sp read -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ws_s_GetCargoClearanceApproval_t]
@BOLID INT,
@ACCOUNTID INT,
@TOTALAMOUNT FLOAT OUT,
@STORAGEDAYS INT OUT,
@ACCOUNTCREDIT FLOAT OUT,
@CREDITLIMIT FLOAT OUT
AS

BEGIN
--SET NOCOUNT ON
    set @TOTALAMOUNT= '25.00'; SET @STORAGEDAYS = 5; SET @ACCOUNTCREDIT =2500.00;  SET @CREDITLIMIT=75000.00 ;
    select @TOTALAMOUNT,@STORAGEDAYS,@ACCOUNTCREDIT,@CREDITLIMIT;
END
```

to fetch the data i had to modify the sp to read

```
select @TOTALAMOUNT as TotalAmount,@STORAGEDAYS as StorageDays,@ACCOUNTCREDIT as AccountCredit,@CREDITLIMIT as CreditLimit;
```

in this case i did not have to set the output params either, everyone is happy :)